# Control Eclipse Validation

Tags: eclipse, validation, jsf, xhtml

The validation of my JSF .xhtml files in Eclipse lasts several minutes!

I don't know what the problem is.. It's always the same .xhtml file that requires so much time..

I know that I can disable all the Validators in Eclipse, but that's not what I want!

Does anybody has some tipps, which Validators to enable in `Preferences > Validation` and which ones to disable?

And can I somehow find out which validator is currently running?
So that I can disable the one that lasts so long...

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 16):

[image: Here is a screenshot]

There are three Preferences in Eclipse Juno that you would need to uncheck/disable:

1. Facelet HTML Validator
2. JSF View Application Configuration Validator
3. JSF View Validator

Comment: A bit of extra info: if you find that Eclipse ignores this and validates *anyway*, then you may have Validation enabled on a Project by Project basis. To verify, right click on the Project, select Properties and then select the Validation tab.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the reason for the long delay is, that Eclipse tries to download all XML-Schemas and DTDs it does not have in its own cache. Since many of them are not directly downloadable (e.g. internal ones), Eclipse has to wait for a network timeout.

Normally, I simply disable the entire validation stuff. For JSP/JSF it gets confused too easily anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Additional answer to the following question: "can I somehow find out which validator is currently running?"

You can open the "Progress" view and if the Facelet HTML Validator is running you'll see a message "Facelet HTML Validator starting to validate: name-of-file.xhtml".

In my case it takes more than a dozen minutes to validate all files. 
Disabling only the "Facelet HTML Validator" (and none of the other validators, see the answer of Neil Griffin) helped in my case and reduced the build time extremely. I just have to remember to enable it or run automatically if I'll need it.